# Environment Server's get_trajectory_validity is not being advertised

Tags: ros, planning-environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ROS diamondback with our custom arm, I'm trying to get move_arm to work. My current problem is that the environment_server is not advertising a get_trajectory_validity service. I am trying to ignore any obstacles in the environment for now.

Here's the launch file that I am using for the environment service

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="planning_environment" type="environment_server" output="screen" name="environment_server">
    <param name="allow_valid_collisions" type="bool" value="false" />

    <param name="collision_map_safety_timeout" type="double" value="100000.0" />
    <param name="joint_states_safety_timeout" type="double" value="1.0" />
    <param name="tf_safety_timeout" type="double" value="1.0" />
    <param name="bounding_planes" type="string" value="0 0 1 -0.01" />

    <param name="object_padd" type="double" value="0.04" />
    <param name="pointcloud_padd" type="double" value="0.00" />

    <param name="contacts_to_compute_for_display" type="int" value="50" />
    <param name="joint_state_cache_allowed_difference" type="double" value=".1" />

    <param name="use_collison_map" value="false" />

    <param name="default_robot_padding" value="0.01" />

  </node>
</launch>
```

The error I get (from move_arm) is:

```
header: 
  seq: 235
  stamp: 1310568657.618890981
  frame_id: 
level: 2
name: /move_right_arm
msg: waitForService: Service [/environment_server/get_trajectory_validity] has not been advertised, waiting...
file: /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-ros-comm-1.4.7/debian/ros-diamondback-ros-comm/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/service.cpp
function: service::exists
line: 80
topics[]
  topics[0]: /rosout
  topics[1]: /allowed_contact_regions_array
```

I am launching the move_arm node with:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="move_arm" type="move_arm_simple_action" output="screen" name="move_right_arm">

    <remap from="robot_description" to="/robot_description" />
    <remap from="joint_state" to="/joint_states" />
    <remap from="filter_trajectory" to="trajectory_filter/filter_trajectory_with_constraints" />
    <!--remap from="filter_trajectory" to="chomp_planner_longrange/filter_trajectory_with_constraints" /-->

    <remap from="arm_ik" to="/arm_kinematics/get_constraint_aware_ik" />
    <remap from="arm_fk" to="/arm_kinematics/get_fk" />

    <remap from="get_trajectory_validity" to="environment_server/get_trajectory_validity" />
    <remap from="get_environment_safety" to="environment_server/get_environment_safety" />
    <remap from="get_execution_safety" to="environment_server/get_execution_safety" />
    <remap from="get_group_info" to="environment_server/get_group_info" />
    <remap from="get_robot_state" to="environment_server/get_robot_state" />
    <remap from="get_state_validity" to="environment_server/get_state_validity" />


    <param name="group" type="string" value="right_arm" />
    <param name="ik_allowed_time" type="double" value="2.0" />
    <param name="trajectory_filter_allowed_time" type="double" value="2.0" />
    <param name="group" type="string" value="right_arm" />
    <!-- <param name="controller_action_name" type="string" value="/r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action" /> -->
    <param name="controller_action_name" type="string" value="/right_arm/joint_trajectory_action" />

    <param name="pause_allowed_time" type="double" value="5.0" />

  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10587/environment-server%27s-get_trajectory_validity-is-not-being-advertised/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-07-13**:
I am not seeing the get_trajectory_validity service from the environmental server when I run rosservice list, is that normal?

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-13**:
Can you post how you launch move_arm, what remapping are done there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the problem (as you can see in my posted launch file) is that I spelled "collision" wrong for the use_collision_map parameter. Perhaps it would be nice to add in a way for unused parameters that are specified.

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is all in diamondback, correct? (Things are very different on unstable/e-turtle and we have a few new tools that should make getting arm_navigation working on your arm much easier).

In diamondback the environment_server should be advertising this in its local namespace so all your configuration looks correct.  Given that you have use_collision_map set to false I expect the problem is in your publishing of the /joint_states topic - the environment server will not turn over and advertise its services until it has received a published value for each of the degrees of freedom specified in your URDF.

Once you've launched the environment server you can see what joints its still waiting on by running rxconsole and setting the logger levels for the environment_server planning_environment level to DEBUG.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-07-13**:
I'm getting lots of: TF operating on not fully resolved frame id world, resolving using local prefix  messages, is this the likely culprit?

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-07-13**:
You shouldn't need to publish anything about fixed joints on the /joint_states topic - that only specifies the positions of joints that can move.  robot_state_publisher also subscribes to this topic and will use it to publish the full tf tree including for fixed joints.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-13**:
robot_state_publisher node will publish fixed joints based on URDF, it also subscribes to /joint_states to get state information about all moving joints and then publishes all this to TF.

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-07-13**:
Would a joint_state need to be published for a fixed joint? And yes, it is in diamondback.